# Finding the longest non-negative sub array

Tags: performance, algorithm, arrays

I'm looking for an more efficient alternative to brute force for finding the longest sub array of an array with a non-negative sum. The numbers range from -5 to 5 in this array.

For example, if you have an array `A`:

4 2 -5 3 0 -2 -2 -3 4 -4 -3 -2 1

then the longest non-negative sub array is

4 2 -5 3 0 -2 -2 -3 4, with the length of 9

The solution I'm thinking of is to keeping tack of a best solution, and a best suffix, where the best suffix always ends with the last point checked `A[i]`. If the best suffix is ever longer than best solution, we update the best solution to the best suffix.

The suffix would be made of a negative subarray sandwiched between two positive sub arrays.
So, in this case starting from left to right:

4 2 is the first positive sub array
-5 is the negative sub array
3 0 -2 is second positive sub array

Then the program checks if the sum of two positive sub arrays is larger than the negative sub array. If so, the whole best suffix becomes the new first positive sub arrays. If not, then the first positive and negative sub array are dumped and the second positive sub array becomes the first sub array, and so on.

In theory the program should be able to incrementally check for the best solution in linear time.

**But this answer seems to be incorrect.**

So Im looking for a better solution for this, or at-least a hint towards a better direction

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the "longest biased interval" and is a common problem in biology. Here is the algorithm (where in your case `L==0`):

```
Input: A nonempty array of n real numbers `A[1 . . . n]` and a lower bound `L`.

Output: The start and end index of the longest segment of `A` with sum at least `L`.

C[0 . . . n] and M[0 . . . n] are arrays of size n +1, as defined in the context.

M[0]←C[0]←0; x←y←0;
for i←1 to n do
    C[i]←C[i −1] + A[i];
    if C[i −1]<C[M[i −1]] then M[i]←i −1 else M[i] = M[i −1];
    k←i −y +x − 1;
    while k >0 do
        if C[i] − C[M[k]] >= L then k←M[k] else break;
        x←k +1; y←i;
    end while
    OUTPUT A(x, y);
end for
```

See Chen, Kuan-Yu, and Kun-Mao Chao. "Optimal algorithms for locating the longest and shortest segments satisfying a sum or an average constraint." Information Processing Letters 96.6 (2005): 197-201.

Here is an illustration of the concept:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### HINTS

You can do this in linear time by:

1. First compute the cumulative sum of your array A
2. Then compute an array B giving the greatest value in A to the right of index i
3. And compute an array C giving the smallest value in A to the left of index i

Both B and C will be non-increasing arrays.

Then for each start position in array C, compute the greatest end position in array B such that B[end]>C[start].  This can be done in linear time by:

1. start with start=0
2. increment end until B[end+1]<=C[start]
3. increment start and return to step 2

The greatest value of end-start corresponds to the longest subarray.

### Explanation

The main idea is that once you have a cumulative sum of your array you can compute the value of a subarray by doing a subtraction.

For example, the array:

```
4 2 -5 3 0 -2
```

has cumulative values:

```
A = [4 6 1 4 4 2]
```

So to find the sum of the second, third, fourth entries (indices 1,2,3 with values 2,-5,3) we can compute:

```
A[3]-A[0] = 4 - 4 = 0
```

and so your problem now reduces to finding pairs of values in array A that are furthest apart and also have A[end]>A[start].

Answer (score 0):

you can keep track of 11 things for each element while using dynamic programming, moving from left to right. Those 11 things correspond to the following possible sum : 
-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
For each of these you need to store the left most index, such that sum of the subarray starting at that index and ending in the current index gives that much sum.
This is not a complete solution, but I believe this may serve the purpose of hint.