# Find out the maximum sub-array of non negative numbers from an array

Tags: c, arrays

`A : [1, 2, 5, -7, 2, 3]` The two sub-arrays are `[1, 2, 5]` `[2, 3]`. 
The answer is `[1, 2, 5]`as its sum is larger than `[2, 3]`

NOTE: If there is a tie, then compare with segment's length and return segment which has maximum length.
NOTE 2: If there is still a tie, then return the segment with minimum starting index.

I have written the code and its working for some cases but not for this one :

```
A : [ 1967513926, 1540383426, -1303455736, -521595368 ]
Your function returned the following :
1967513926 
The expected returned value :
1967513926 1540383426
```

Here is my code

```
int* maxset(int* A, int n1, int *length_of_array) {

     int greatin=0,greatout=0,greatin1=0,number1=0,number=0;
     int n3,i,count=0,k,sum=0,max=0,ini=0,end=0;

     for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
     {
         ini=end;
         if(A[i]>=0)
         {
             count=1;
             number++;
             sum=sum+A[i];
             if (sum>max )
             {

                 max=sum;
                 greatout=i;
                 greatin=ini;

             }
             else if (sum==max && number>number1)
             {
                  max=sum;
                 greatout=i;
                 greatin=ini;
             }
         }
        else
        {
            sum=0;
            end=i+1;
            number1=number;
            number=0;

        }
     }
    if(count>0)
    {
          count=0;
          n3=greatout-greatin+1;
          *length_of_array=n3;
          int * ret = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * *length_of_array);

          for(i=greatin;count<n3;i++)
          {
               ret[count]=A[i];
               count++;

          } 
     return ret;

    }
    else
     {

      *length_of_array=0;
      int * ret = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * *length_of_array);
      return ret;
     }
}
```

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713781/finding-the-longest-non-negative-sub-array

Comment: That is a different question beacuse in that, the array can include a negetive number which requires the whole sum of the subarray to be non negetive..But in this the sub array cannot have a negetive number..

Comment: So whenever you encounter a negative value, remove the value and split the array?

Comment: Yea, whenever a negetive value is encountered in the array, until that part becomes the subarray and the next subarray starts after that negetive value. We have to now find the maximum of the sub arrays..We arent actually removing the negetive value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using int and when you add you overflow the limit  2,147,483,647

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working program in python for your question:

```
def check(max_arr,curr):
    if sum(curr) > sum(max_arr):
                max_arr = curr
    elif sum(curr) == sum(max_arr):
        if len(curr) > len(max_arr):
            max_arr = curr
        elif len(curr) == len(max_arr):
            if max_arr and (curr[0] > max_arr[0]):
                max_arr = curr
    return max_arr

def maxset(A):
    curr = []
    max_arr = []
    for i in A:
        if i >= 0:
            curr.append(i)
        else:
            max_arr = check(max_arr,curr)
            curr = []
    max_arr = check(max_arr,curr)                    
    return max_arr
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.